# Trouble with deployment of firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to develop some skills with cloud functions and firebase, but i am having a small trouble from the start. I believe there is a easy solution to this, but i have been trying to solve it for a few days now without any success... So, what i am doing - i am following this tutorial's steps 
/ ~ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM ~ /. At the end, i am deploying the firebase and according to the video, i must see the project console's HTTP and the FUNCTION URL
[image: Screenshot from TUTORIAL]

Its all fun and roses until i try the exact same steps and i see only the Project Console's http:
[image: Screenshot from MY_PROJECT]
I am pretty sure i am missing some part, but as i replayed the whole video 3 times, i guess it is something that is not said there... Also, i do not see the cloud function in my Firebase project, as shown in the video:
[image: Functions in YOUTUBE_TUTORIAL]

I do not have anything in my project.
What i've tried so far:
updating NPM, 
updating FIREBASE TOOLS,
Starting a new project,
Overwriting existing project. Nothing. I am assuming i've missed a vital part and i apologize in advance for the (what i think) quite stupid question. I cannot find any solution whatsoever... Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you selecting "functions" from the list when you initialize the project in the terminal?

Comment: Hmm. "firebase init" is how i am initializing the project, i am missing something?

Comment: When you call `firebase init`, it asks you to select the features you want to initialize. You need to select functions from that list.

Comment: Oh yes, silly me. I do this.

Comment: If you've already initialized a project, you can add Functions to it with `firebase init functions`.